# Can ViewModel have property of type IEnumerable<> instead of Array

Tags: c#, properties, viewmodel, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

I generally construct my `ViewModel` like this:

```
MyViewModel {
  (...)
  IEnumerable<MyClass> Items {get; set;}
}
```

Should I ever care (be afraid) that I am not passing an already evaluated values like in code below?

```
MyViewModel {
  MyClass[] Items {get; set;}
}
```

Sometimes lazy evaluation causes some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure to new up the concrete instance of the IEnumerable in your View Model Constructor, and you shouldn't have any problems.  The list will just be empty.

Answer (score 1):

> **Should I ever care (be afraid) that I am not passing already evalueted values like in code below?**

No, because you're not *passing them anywhere*. To be more clear, the code evaluated in the `View` is evaluated and run server-side, so there is nothing wrong with using `IEnumerable` here. You could manage any of those problems in the view, just like you would anywhere else. In fact, if it's a very large list it might be more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ever care (be afraid) that I am not passing already evalueted
>   values like in code below?

At least, you should remember, that enumerator can be endless:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers
    {
        get
        {
            while (true)
            {
                yield return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, indeed, it isn't a cause to refuse lazy enumerated properties. This is just a reason to be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

if you have choice, Never bind to IEnumerable.

Bind **IList** to **ItemsControl** not **IEnumerable**  Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you really care about performance